# Augmented Reality android App using Wikitude

Tags: android, augmented-reality, wikitude

I want to implement android app to recognize buildings using wikitude but i can not find any sample that  can only recognize 3d scene i tried to modify in the inernalrendering class in their example to load my .wtm file but nothing happened 
is there any open source application i can look at? or any tutorials for 3d tracking using wikitude ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after hours of trying i found that all the wikitude examples was indoors and my app should work outdoor so i moved to vuforia and used their 2d images not 3d model storing multiple images of the buildings i want.